# Python convert string to float error with negative numbers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

How to convert a negative number stored as string to a float?

Am getting this error on Python 3.6 and don't know how to get over it.

```
>>> s = '–1123.04'
>>> float(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '–1123.04'
```

Comment: FWIW, you can use the standard `unicodedata` module to get the name of each char in string that's behaving mysteriously. Eg, if the string is `s` do `import unicodedata as ud` `print(*map(ud.name, s), sep=', ')`. See the module docs for more nifty functions. And of course you can do `print(s.encode('unicode-escape'))`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your string contains a unicode en-dash, not an ASCII hyphen.  You could replace it:

```
>>> float('–1123.04'.replace('\U00002013', '-'))
-1123.04
```

Comment: You can throw [this](https://pastebin.com/hvm4yDpK) in there if you want to show the difference, if you like.

Comment: can you explain how you see the exact unicode type.  I have a slightly different dash and was wondering how to fix my issue

Comment: @qwertylpc: See the comment on the question by Pm 2Ring.  You can also use `.encode('unicode-escape')` to get a representation that will use backslash-escape representations for non-ASCII Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic solution, you can use regular expressions (regex) to replace all non-ascii characters with a hyphen.

```
import re

s = '–1123.04'

s = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','-', s)

s = float(s)
```