# Python- problem converting negative numbers to floats, issues with hyphen encoding

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a Pandas dataframe that I've read from a file - `pd.read_csv()` - and I'm having trouble converting a column with string values to float.

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure why pandas is even reading the column as string files to begin with - all the values are numeric. The problem seems to be with the hyphen minus sign for the negative numbers. There are other threads on this topic that mention how em-dash can mess things up ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269652/python-convert-string-to-float-error-with-negative-numbers), for example)

However, when I try converting the hyphen type, it still gives me an error. For example,

```
df['Verified_m'] = df['Verified_m'].str.replace("\U00002013", "-").astype(float)
```

doesn't change anything; all the values start with the `'-'` hyphen, so it's not actually replacing anything. It still gives me the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

I've tried replacing all of the hyphens with a numeric value to see if that would work, and I'm able to convert to float (example: `df['Verified_m'] = df['Verified_m'].str.replace("-", "0").astype(float)` . But I'd like to retain the negative values in the dataset. Does anyone know what's wrong with my hyphens?

Comment: That error means you have some values that are just `-`, without a number after it.

Comment: @KillerRebooted Why would he want to convert the positive numbers to negative? He just wants to parse the numbers that begin with a minus sign as negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Verified_m'] = df['Verified_m'].str.replace("\U00002013", "-").str.replace(r'^-$', '0', regex=True).astype(float)
```

After converting the em-dashes to hyphens, it converts a lone `-` to zero.